# Replace the string with "*" after some interval in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

I am trying to mask/hide some sensitive data say example as Bearer token. So suppose i have some string "`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890`" and i want to display it as "`abcde*************************`". I want to show only stating 7-8 character from starting and after that i want to replace with any symbol (here its "*")

Any leads will be help full.

Comment: If `s` is your string and `n` the number of not hidden characters: `s[:n] + '*' * (len(s)-n)`

Comment: It worked. Can you please explain me a bit @Matthias

Comment: I've got no time now, but this is your chance to learn. Open the tutorial and read about strings. You might even learn more things that might help you later.

Comment: @Matthias: I would add this as an answer so that you can get a proper recognition for it.

Comment: Just to get the missing points I need for 10k rep? I'm no point hunter and I really have no time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think It can be useful.

```
def mask(TOKEN, NUM=5, SYMBOL='*'):
    return TOKEN.replace(TOKEN[NUM:], SYMBOL * (len(TOKEN) - NUM))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TEST_CASE = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'
    print(mask(TOKEN=TEST_CASE))
```